# Estou tendo um erro em meu programa em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou tendo o seguinte erro na linha 13 coluna 39:

`[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]`

É para um trabalho da faculdade, não consigo corrigir o erro de forma alguma, alguém sabe o que fazer?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char conc(char *, char *);

int main (void)
{
    char nome1[30] = "Matheus ";
    char nome2[30] = "Fidelis";

    char *nomecompleto = conc(nome1,nome2);

    cout << *nomecompleto;
}

char conc(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *s = new char[strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1];
    char *aux = s;

    while(*s1) 
    {
        *aux = *s1;
        aux++;
        s1++;
    }

    while(*s2)
    {
        *aux = *s2;
        aux++;
        s2++;
    }
    *aux = '\0';
    return *s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando salvar na variável `nomecompleto` o retorno da função `conc(nome1,nome2);`, porém os tipos não batem.

`nomecompleto` é um ponteiro *(de char)*, enquanto a fun `conc()` retorna um char.

Para corrigir isso basta trocar o retorno e o tipo da função `conc`.

No começo do código, na definição da função:

```
char* conc(char *, char *);
```

E em sua implementação:

```
char* conc(char *s1, char *s2){
  char *s = new char[strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1]; //(inalterado)
  [...]
  return s;
}
```

Observe que a variável `s`já é um ponteiro, com isso ao executar `return s;` você já estará passando o endereço de memória que foi alocado para o novo char (esse é o objetivo).

Quando você retorna `*s`, você cria uma cópia do char salvo no endereço que o ponteiro `s` aponta, então você estaria retornando um char onde é esperado um ponteiro (esse não é o objetivo, com isso o erro iria persistir).

**OBS:** Isso resolve o erro de conversão inválida, porém seu código possui outros erros de lógica, que irão impedir a saída esperada.

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me ser um erro na inicialização da variável do tipo ponteiro para char `*nomecompleto` a qual recebe um valor do tipo char da função conc `conc(nome1,nome2);`
em `char *nomecompleto = conc(nome1,nome2);`